Search api autocomplete suggestion punctuation removal
I am using Search-api-autocomplete module for search suggestion. I am looking to remove punctuation from the suffix of search suggestion( The list of suggestions, for example, "word,", I would like to remove the comma from the suggestion list. Will be great if anybody can help me with this.

You could modify the input field so that no comma can be entered, e.g. use the attribute pattern.
pattern="[^\\x2c]*"

